# "pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile" when not using Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's my problem:

- I create a new project: `rails new myapp`.
  Rails applications are by default configured to use a SQLite3 database.
- I execute `bundle exec rake db:create`. It works and the SQLite3 database is created.
- I try to create a new model (or anything else related to the database), and get the following error:

  > /home/dinduks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:147:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the postgresql adapter:`gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
- When I add a controller and an action, and try to visit it, I get this error:

  > ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)

  The complete stack trace can be found here: https://gist.github.com/2717365
  The WEBrick server starts obviously without complaining.

I reinstalled Rails, reinstalled Ruby, used another Ruby version, reinstalled RVM... And keep getting the same error.

There is **nothing** related to *PostgreSQL*, *postgres*, *pg* or *pql* in my code. Not a single word.

I don't want to do what the exception suggests. I want to understand why I have this error and fix it.

So: Why is Rails asking me to install some Postgres stuff while **I don't use Postgres**?

Thanks!

Comment: what's the content of `database.yml`? what's the output of `echo $DATABASE_URL` in shell? can you start the rails server?

Comment: Can you paste your Gemfile here? Also, have you tried running `bundle install`?

Comment: also paste the Gemfile.lock too, just in case one of those sneaky gems added it as a dependency.

Comment: @NARKOZ: I had something in my local *$DATABASE_URL*, but I removed it and still got the same error. -- I updated my question with the files content.

Comment: are you able to start rails server?

Comment: @NARKOZ I am. But I can't visit an action I created.

Comment: @NARKOZ Thanks for pointing out `$DATABASE_URL`. When I first tried to remove it, I simply deleted it from *.bash_env* (one of my custom bash config files) and `source ~/.bash_rb` (also opened a new terminal). I should have overwrote it. I did it and now it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.
When ActiveRecord finds `$DATABASE_URL`, it automatically uses its information, and ignores *config/database.yml*.

Thanks to NARKOZ for pointing this out.

(By the way, I had this environment variable set before I discover [foreman](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#local_setup), which is a great tool to manage environment variables)

Comment: Thanks!! Totally saved hours!